# Is there a calculation error in my program?

Tags: c++, function

Apparently there is a calculation error somewhere in my program, but I simply can’t find it.

The only information I have as to why there is a calculation error is this following feedback given by MyProgrammingLab (A site that automatically tests code to see if it's incorrect or not). I don't know what values were entered for the annual death rate and annual birth rate to cause it. Could it be that I'm right but MyProgrammingLab is wrong? Honestly, all my own tests seem fine.

**Expected Output:**

```
Year 1: 200 176
Year 2: 176 154
Year 3: 154 135
Year 4: 135 118
Year 5: 118 103
Year 6: 103 90
Year 7: 90 79
```

**Actual Output:**

```
Year 1: 200 199
Year 2: 199 198
Year 3: 198 197
Year 4: 197 196
Year 5: 196 195
Year 6: 195 194
Year 7: 194 193
```

**I built the program according to the following assignment:**

In a population, the birth rate is the percentage increase  of the population due to births, and the death rate is the percentage decrease  of the population due to deaths. Write a program  that asks for the following:

- The starting size of a population (minimum 2) (Prompt `Enter starting size:`)
- The annual birth rate (Prompt `Enter annual birth rate:`)
- The annual death rate (Prompt `Enter annual death rate:`)
- The number of years to display (minimum 1) (Prompt `Enter years to display:`)

The program  should then display the starting population and the projected population at the end of each year. It should use a function that calculates and returns the projected new size of the population after a year. The formula is

```
  N = P(1 + B)(1 - D)
```

where N is the new population size, P is the previous population size, B is the birth rate, and D is the death rate. Annual birth rate and death rate are the typical number of births and deaths in a year per 1000 people, expressed as a decimal. So, for example, if there are normally about 32 births and 26 deaths per 1000 people in a given  population, the birth rate would be .032 and the death rate would be .026.

**My code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int projectedNewSize(float population, float annualBirthRate, float annualDeathRate) {
    float annualBirthRate2 = annualBirthRate / 1000;
    float annualDeathRate2 = annualDeathRate / 1000;

    int newpopulation = population * (1 + annualBirthRate2) * (1 - annualDeathRate2);
    return newpopulation;
}

int main() {

    int populationStartingSize = 0;
    float annualBirthRate = 0;
    float annualDeathRate = 0;
    int numberOfYearsToDisplay = 0;

    do  {
        cout << "Enter starting population size: ";
        cin >> populationStartingSize;
        cout << "Enter annual birth rate: ";
        cin >> annualBirthRate;
        cout << "Enter annual death rate: ";
        cin >> annualDeathRate;
        cout << "Enter years to display: ";
        cin >> numberOfYearsToDisplay;
    } while (!(populationStartingSize >= 2) || !(numberOfYearsToDisplay >= 1));

    int population;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfYearsToDisplay; i++) {
        cout << "Year " << i << ": " << populationStartingSize << " ";
        population = projectedNewSize(populationStartingSize, annualBirthRate, annualDeathRate);
        cout << population << endl;
        populationStartingSize = population;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Well written question. Includes expected and actual output, clear problem statement, own first effort and relevant code.

Comment: When you run the code through the tester, can you see console output? Perhaps you could output to the console the received parameters.

Comment: are the birth/death rates given as int (32) or float (0.032) ? Because you may divide unnecessary by 1000. And you are truncating when casting your float to int for newpopulation, hence 200 minus something very small equals 199

Comment: Please output the values of `annualBirthRate` and `annualDeathRate` in your loop.

Comment: The only console output the tester gives is the mentioned Actual Output. And the only parameter whose value I know is populationStartingSize, which is 200. The annualBirthRate and annualDeathRate values the tester is using are unknown to me, and there's no way I can find out.

Comment: @Learner - What stops you from doing a `cout << annualBirthRate` in the `for` loop?

Comment: You create the actual output from your cout statements, no? So you can output additional debugging information.

Comment: @Florent They should be given as an int.

Comment: @Learner `cout << "Year " << i << ": " << populationStartingSize << " " << annualBirthRate << " " << annualDeathRate;`  That's all you need to do, and you will see what the data is.  There is no secret.

Comment: @NeilKirk +1 from me too.  It's very unusual to read a question like this; I'm going to have a double Highland Park and lie down for a bit to recover from the shock.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie When I do that, it gives another Expected Output entirely, and no Actual Output information at all.

Comment: *"They should be given as int"* -- The instructions, as you give them, seem unclear on this point. Have you tried *not* dividing by 1000, and seeing what results you get?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Okay, I got it. It gives back 0 for both annualDeathRate and annualBirthRate.

Comment: To get such a big decrease the first year, you would need a hefty net death rate (decrease from 200 to 176 is over 10%, or over 100 per thousand). For example, death rate of 220 and birth rate of 100 gives a population of 171 at end of first year if you start at 200 inhabitants. Also, I suggest changing all float's to doubles.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley You were right! My code was accepted as correct once I simply removed the division by 1000.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley May I ask how you came to the conclusion that dividing by 1000 might be the problem? Was it just because the instructions were unclear, or did something else in the output give it away? Thanks!

Comment: @Learner: See Florent's comment.

Comment: What are the actual inputs, 32 or 0.032?

Comment: Your first prompt is wrong: "Enter starting population size: " should be "Enter starting size: ".

Comment: @Werner Henze Yeah, you'd think so because that's what the instructions say to make it, but the program that checks my answer wanted it to be "Enter starting population size:" Sorry for the confusion there.

Answer (score 3):

So, The answer is

There is no need to divide the annualBirthRate and the annualDeathRate by 1000. Since annualBirthRate is calculated as annual births per 1000 of a population, It need not be divided by 1000 again.

Thus removing these lines

```
float annualBirthRate2 = annualBirthRate / 1000;
float annualDeathRate2 = annualDeathRate / 1000;
```

and changing

```
int newpopulation = population * (1 + annualBirthRate2) * (1 - annualDeathRate2);
```

to

```
int newpopulation = population * (1 + annualBirthRate) * (1 - annualDeathRate);
```

So, the final code would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int projectedNewSize(float population, float annualBirthRate, float annualDeathRate) {

    int newpopulation = population * (1 + annualBirthRate) * (1 - annualDeathRate);
    return newpopulation;
}

int main() {

    int populationStartingSize = 0;
    float annualBirthRate = 0;
    float annualDeathRate = 0;
    int numberOfYearsToDisplay = 0;

    do  {
        cout << "Enter starting population size: ";
        cin >> populationStartingSize;
        cout << "Enter annual birth rate: ";
        cin >> annualBirthRate;
        cout << "Enter annual death rate: ";
        cin >> annualDeathRate;
        cout << "Enter years to display: ";
        cin >> numberOfYearsToDisplay;
    } while (!(populationStartingSize >= 2) || !(numberOfYearsToDisplay >= 1));

    int population;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfYearsToDisplay; i++) {
        cout << "Year " << i << ": " << populationStartingSize << " ";
        population = projectedNewSize(populationStartingSize, annualBirthRate, annualDeathRate);
        cout << population << endl;
        populationStartingSize = population;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

You guys discussed in the comments section and left the question unanswered..

Comment: -1 for just doing a code dump. Please explain what you changed, and why it fixes the issue.

Comment: The reason it wasn't answered is because it's off topic. The question has little to do with programming. It has more to do with figuring out how to correctly interpret somebody's poorly written instructions.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley so what..? Leaving the question unanswered isn't correct either.. It appears in the unanswered list.. Nothing wrong in answering the question..

Comment: On the contrary, leaving the question unanswered is in fact the correct action for off-topic questions. And if you have the rep, further correct action is to vote to close it.

Comment: Anyway, I don't really care that you answered it. I was just responding to your note at the bottom of your answer, since you seemed to be wondering why we didn't post an answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for extending your answer -- I reverted my -1. And contrary to @BenjaminLindley I think it's a perfectly valid question which certainly deserves an answer. Especially since the OP clearly put some effort in posting a nice question.

Answer (score 2):

```
int projectedNewSize(float population, float annualBirthRate, float annualDeathRate) {

    int newpopulation = roundf(population * (1.0 + annualBirthRate) * (1.0 - annualDeathRate);
    return newpopulation;
}
```

In the calculatiton you dont have to consider the factor of 1000 if it is already done in the input values. But if you want a 'most accurate' table you have to round the values in a proper mind. The return of the calculation is a float. If you assign it to an int - it always will be truncated. A little difference wich will be carried over from one loop to the next, ending up in some reasonable differences to the expected values at the end. The most proper way would be to change the type of 'newcalculation' to float and round only when display the value.

Comment: Correct rounding in these cases is **very** hard. Population statistics are generally statistical in nature. Hence, it's unlikely that you'll be rounding down in exactly 50% of the cases. Even if you are, it's unlikely that you'll round down an average of -0.25 and round up an average of +0.25.  If you're learning to program, this basically boils down to "don't worry about being one off if it's rare"

Answer (score 1):

N = P + BP - DP

Program asked for birthrate and death rate, assume user entered **5** for 5%. 
Basic math needs to be calculated here 5/100 = 0.05

The formula is now

N = P + (BP/100) - (DP/100)

Replace

```
    float annualBirthRate2 = annualBirthRate / 1000;
    float annualDeathRate2 = annualDeathRate / 1000;

    int newpopulation = population * (1 + annualBirthRate2) * (1 - annualDeathRate2);
```

With

```
    int newpopulation = population + (population * birthRate/100) - (population * deathRate/100)
```